# Angular5 service not sending data?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, rxjs

My code has 2 components, A and B. A has a form with data in it. I want to send the data from the form in component A to component B. But it looks like B isn't getting any data.

Component A:

```js
import { MyService } from 'path/myService.service';
@Component({
  //blah blah
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {

  //my form data

  constructor(private myServ: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onChange(event) {
    const data = event.target.value;
    this.myServ.changeMessage(data);
    console.log("sent");
  }
}
```

Component B:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from 'path/myService.service';

@Component({
  // blah blah
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class ComponentB implements OnInit {

  recievedData = null;

  constructor(private myServ: MyService) {} 

  // i tried putting this in constructor instead, but it still didn't work
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myServ.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
      console.log(message);
      this.recievedData = message
    });
  }
}
```

My Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  changeMessage(message) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

The console.log("sent") fires in Component A's onChange method, but the console.log(message) never fires in Component B's subscribe codeblock. Any ideas?

Comment: comp A is using this.toggleService but it is not injecting that service

Comment: excellent job on your first post, you've included the crucial parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide MyService (see the providers array in @Component) in each component, so each component has its own instance of the service. Remove providers from component metadata

Answer (score 0):

When I've used `BehaviorSubject` I've needed to subscribe to the observable and specify `async` and use `await` on the response. In component b it would look like this for you:

```
this.toggleService.currentMessage.subscribe(async(message) => 
{
  this.recievedData = await message;
});
```